# Concatenating in sub select statement slows down query performance significantly . SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have simple select statement that gives me result for around one second. But if I add sub-select statement which generates column `'Sent to UW on'` then the performance is slows down significantly. 
I think the reason is in exactly this statement:

```
OR L.Action = CONCAT('Conrol #',Q.ControlNo, '. Change Quote Status Reason from ''None'' to ''Under Review''')
```

Is any other way to rewrite this `select` statement?

```
SELECT   
    ControlNo , 
   PolicyNumber , 
   l.LineName , 
   InsuredPolicyName , 
   DisplayStatus , 
   U.UserName as Underwriter , 
   u.EmailAddress as 'Underwriter Email' , 
   rtrim(ltrim(PC.[FName])) + ' ' + rtrim(ltrim(PC.[LName])) as Broker , 
   PL.Name , 
   q.DateBound , 
   q.EffectiveDate , 
   (  
    SELECT TOP 1 L.ActionDate  
    FROM tblLog L  
    WHERE L.IndentifierGuid = q.QuoteGUID  
    AND L.Action = 'Reason for Quote status change: Under Review' 
--The line below slows down the performance  
    OR L.Action = CONCAT('Conrol #',Q.ControlNo, '. Change Quote Status Reason from ''None'' to ''Under Review''')  
   ORDER BY L.ActionDate asc  
   ) as 'Sent to UW on'  
FROM        tblQuotes Q  WITH  ( nolock )  
JOIN        tblUsers U  WITH  ( nolock )  ON underwriteruserguid = u.userGUID  
LEFT JOIN   lstlines L  WITH  ( nolock )  ON L.LineGUID = Q.lineguid  
LEFT JOIN   lstQuoteStatusReasons QSR  WITH  ( nolock )  ON QSR.ID = Q.QuoteStatusReasonID  
LEFT JOIN   [MEJAMES].[dbo].[tblProducerContacts] PC  WITH  ( nolock )  ON pc.ProducerContactGUID = q.ProducerContactGuid  
LEFT JOIN   MEJAMES.DBO.tblProducerLocations PL  WITH  ( nolock )  ON PC.ProducerLocationGUID = PL.ProducerLocationGUID  
LEFT JOIN   [MEJAMES].[dbo].[tblProducerContacts] PC_Asst  WITH  ( nolock )  ON PC_Asst.ProducerContactGUID = q.SecProducerContactGuid  
WHERE       q.lineGUID in( 'D4983D4A-1D12-461D-8837-6092DC74325B', 'CF144437-F128-4B77-AC19-877247347D02' , 'E05E7F4A-07C4-4981-BD13-2461D4EE4BF3')  
   /* EQ and Wind and Terrorism LOBs  */  
    AND q.OriginalQuoteGUID is null  
    AND Q.QuoteStatusID = 3  
    AND Q.EffectiveDate > '5-1-2017'  
ORDER BY q.ControlNo
```

The piece of my Estimated Execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Are you missing parenthesis? The `OR` predicate is independent of the preceding `L.IndentifierGuid = q.QuoteGUID`.

Comment: You also have two "L" aliases... one in the sub select and one as a LEFT JOIN outside it... that's confusing at best. But basically, that concatenation can't use the index, so it has to go to the clustered primary key to do the test. And yeah, you seem to be missing parentheses (open after the AND, and close before the ORDER).

Comment: @Dan Guzman You were correct.  Parenthesis did the job. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things wrong here - addressing them should help you.
There's the issue in the comment by Dan Guzman of the (assumed) missing parenthesis.
You have (numbering mine):

```
WHERE L.IndentifierGuid = q.QuoteGUID   --1
    AND L.Action = 'Reason for Quote status change: Under Review'  --2
--The line below slows down the performance  
    OR L.Action = CONCAT('Conrol #',Q.ControlNo, '. Change Quote Status Reason from ''None'' to ''Under Review''')   --3
```

Which reads as follows: return all rows where condition 1 **AND** 2 are true, or condition 3 is true. While You probably meant to select where condition 1 is true, as well as either condition 2 **OR** 3. If this is what you meant to express, you would need to encapsulate conditions 2 and 3 in parenthesis. If this is correct, you'll likely get a different query plan.

You have `NOLOCK` hints permeating your query, which tells me that you likely need some more indexing on those tables.

I would check the actual plan to see if the estimates were on par with the actuals.

Comment: Parenthesis were the culprit. Thank you very much for explanation @Eli